# What is a meaning of a complex roots?

Tags: complex-numbers

In the simplest sense, what does a complex root on the complex plane actually mean? For polynomial equations a root is a x-coordinate of where the curve crosses the x-axis.

I just find it strange how the roots of complex numbers are symmetrical about the origin of the complex plane, yet no such symmetry exists for polynomial roots.

Comment: A root of a polynomial $P$ is some $x$ such that $P(x) = 0$. If $x$ is complex, then $x$ is a complex root. I’m not sure how much simpler I can make it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I just find it strange how the roots of complex numbers are symmetrical about the origin of the complex plane, yet no such symmetry exists for polynomial roots.

Comment: Roots of polynomials need not be symmetrical about the origin. Example here: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=roots+ix%5E3+%2B+x+%2B1

Comment: You seem to be mixing two senses of the word "root".  A *square root* of a complex number $z$ is a special case of the more general meaning of "root of a polynomial" since $x^2 - z = 0$ precisely when $x$ is a square root of $z$.  When necessary we can use different words to mark the distinction between these meaning.  Taking the square root (or more generally an [*n*th root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root)) can be called a *radical* or a *surd*.  The roots of a polynomial $p(x)$ are often called the *zeros* of the polynomial because by definition they satisfy $p(x)=0$.

Comment: Take into account that the roots of other polynomials also have interesting symmetries of their own, just different. For example, all polynomials with real coefficients have their roots symmetric with respect to the real axis.